# Flutter - Local Notifications fail in release mode

Tags: flutter

I added the **flutter_local_notifications** plugin to schedule notifications. In **the debug version** everything works well for both **emulators and real devices**.

However, when I build the app

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

and install the package on a device and run the app, when it comes to the code part that marks the notification (I supposed...)  , the app crashes

How do I find out what's wrong?

I followed the plugin developers instructions and changed the manifest file:

```
                    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        package="com.example.explika">

                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

                        <!-- Tudo relacionado com as notificações -->
                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
                        <!-- Fim relacionado com notificações -->

                        <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
                            calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
                            In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
                            additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
                            FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
                        <application
                            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
                            android:label="Explika"
                            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
                            <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
                            <activity
                                android:name=".MainActivity"
                                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                                <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                                    until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                                    there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                                    defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
                                <meta-data
                                    android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                                    android:value="true" />
                                <intent-filter>
                                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                                </intent-filter>
                            </activity>
                        </application>
                    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what is causing the application to crash:

[ERROR: flutter / shell / platform / android / platform_view_android_jni.cc (39)] java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: Drawable

However, this only happened in the Release version. The solution consists of customizing the ProGuard configuration file and the build.gradle file following the instructions on the plugin page.
I didn't do these steps because until then the Release version worked without problems and because I thought ProGuard configuration file would only be necessary in case want to publish on the Play Store.